# How to Handle Actual Time with Durations in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, date-math

What's the preferred approach to compare a complete `DateTime` instance with an hour, minute, and second which represents an **actual time of day**, with the ability to operate over those triplets (eg `add` hours, minutes seconds..)?

---

My current approach is something like

```
DateTime startHour = new DateTime(1900,1,1,12,25,43);
DateTime endHour = new DateTime(1900,1,1,13,45,32);

// I need to, say, know if a complete DateTime instance 
// is later than startHour plus 15 minutes

DateTime now = DateTime.Now();

startHour = startHour.addMinutes(15);

if (now.CompareTo(new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, startHour.Hour, 
                    startHour.Minute, startHour.Second)) > 0) 
{
    //I can do something now
}
```

This is very cumbersome and even failure prone. `TimeSpan`s are not a solution as far as I can see, because they represent spans and aren't bound by the 24 hours limit (a `TimeSpan` of 56 hours 34 minutes is valid.)

What's the preferred approach for this type of calculations?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Is it merely that TimeSpan can exceed 24 hours? Because you can easily check for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you mean by "is greater than startHour"... but taking

```
TimeSpan startHour = new TimeSpan(12, 25, 43);
if (endHour.TimeOfDay > startHour)
{
    ...
}
```

... works pretty simply.

By all means add argument checking to make sure that you don't specify a value for startHour which is `<` 0 or `>` 23 hours, but that's all pretty easy.

.NET's date and time API is quite primitive (even in 3.5) compared with, say, Joda Time - but in this particular case I think it's not too bad.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard someone refer to the .NET date/time API as "primitive" in a negative tone, and I couldn't disagree more. :)

Comment: @280Z284: Until 3.5 you couldn't even use non-local time zones! Compared with Joda, .NET really is quite primitive. There's no type representing an instant with an associated time zone - just a UTC offset. Blech. Would consider porting Joda if I had more time.

Comment: Yeah, Joda rocks. Especially when compared to native Java Datetime.

Comment: Are there any .NET libraries out there that can help?

Comment: Or, perhaps, a .NET conversion for Joda Time?

Comment: @Erik: Not as far as I know. I keep wondering about a .NET port of Joda Time, but I don't have enough expertise or time...

Answer (score 2):

A little hint - .NET supports arithmetic operations on DateTime objects, and returns a TimeSpan object. Thus, you can do the following:

```
DateTime fromDate = ....
DateTime toDate = ....
TimeSpan diff = toDate - fromDate;
```

and you can expand this to:

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.addMinutes(x);

if ((toDate - fromDate).TotalMinutes > 15) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use TimeSpan for startHour and endHour.
When comparing with now, you should "convert" them to a full DateTime or get the Time with DateTime.TimeOfDay as mentioned by Jon Skeet.

```
TimeSpan startHour = new TimeSpan(12, 25, 43);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if (now.CompareTo(DateTime.Today.Add(startHour)) > 0) {
    //...
}
```

or

```
TimeSpan startHour = new TimeSpan(12, 25, 43);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if (now.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(startHour) > 0) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why do it that way instead of taking the current time of day? And why use CompareTo instead of the handily-overloaded "greater than" operator?

Answer (score 0):

So you're only interested in the time component of the date.

```
if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > startHour.TimeOfDay)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

What's wrong with doing this?

Comment: It will work, but there's no need for the Date part of startHour and endHour.

Comment: Yes, but that's if you assume that the snippet that was provided is the only part of the code that uses startHour. But what if startHour's date value is used elsewhere?