# Find if current time falls in a time range

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Using .NET 3.5

I want to determine if the current time falls in a time range.

So far I have the currentime:

```
DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
currentTime.TimeOfDay;
```

I'm blanking out on how to get the time range converted and compared.
Would this work?

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime("11:59") <= currentTime.TimeOfDay 
    && Convert.ToDateTime("13:01") >= currentTime.TimeOfDay)
{
   //match found
}
```

UPDATE1: Thanks everyone for your suggestions.  I wasn't familiar with the TimeSpan function.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408165/simple-way-to-handle-time-in-c/1408187#1408187

Comment: Do you need to be concerned with crossing midnight?

Comment: crossing midnight isn't a concern but anything that spans midnight  is sure a bane of my programming experience...

Answer (score 323, accepted):

For checking for a time of day use:

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0); //10 o'clock
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0); //12 o'clock
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if ((now > start) && (now < end))
{
   //match found
}
```

For absolute times use:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 12, 9, 10, 0, 0)); //10 o'clock
DateTime end = new DateTime(2009, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0)); //12 o'clock
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if ((now > start) && (now < end))
{
   //match found
}
```

Comment: How to count the number of matches? For example I want to count how many saturdays and sundays are in the range.

Comment: @pmbiesiada: This is completely out of the scope of the original question (and the answer). You should make this a new question, but do a serach here on SO if something like this has been answered before. Good luck.

Comment: What if there are different time for different days? Is there a easy to compare that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769557/how-to-compare-current-time-against-time-of-day

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: Compare for what? Please be more specific about what you want to accomplish or give some examples.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with some help. Thank you :) I wanted to compare the current time with the operation business hours.

Comment: @FrankBollack how to capture the local time while doing this?

Comment: What if your times span goes from 11 pm to 1 am?

Comment: @SamIam: A `Timespan` is simply a relative amount of time, meaning a number of days, hours or seconds. It does not know about "when". The first example compares the time of day by using the amout of time that has passed since the start of the day: e.g. 10 hours meaning 10 o'clock AM.

Comment: @FrankBollack i did not say "`Timespan`"  I said "Time Span"

Comment: The answer below should be the accepted one... This one doesn't check for TimeSpans over days, e.g. from 22:00:00 to 02:00:00...

Answer (score 172):

Some good answers here but none cover the case of your start time being in a different day than your end time.  If you need to straddle the day boundary, then something like this may help:

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("22:00"); // 10 PM
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse("02:00");   // 2 AM
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if (start <= end)
{
    // start and stop times are in the same day
    if (now >= start && now <= end)
    {
        // current time is between start and stop
    }
}
else
{
    // start and stop times are in different days
    if (now >= start || now <= end)
    {
       // current time is between start and stop
    }
}
```

Note that in this example the time boundaries are inclusive and that this still assumes less than a 24-hour difference between `start` and `stop`.

Comment: What if there are different time for different days? Is there a easy to compare that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769557/how-to-compare-current-time-against-time-of-day

Comment: Good point, that makes sense. If the measured time passes through midnight then this would be the only answer that would still be correct.

Comment: thank you, after hours i tried for `11:57 pm` and this worked:

`TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(23, 57, 00);
               DateTime date_with_time = mydate.Add(time);`

Comment: Thank you for that.  The answer seems simple to come to, but it's kinda awkward to conceptualize.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm writing a method to determine whether the time of a given `DateTime` falls within specified business hours. Business hours could be on the same day, but they could also span two days (e.g., 3pm - 1am operating hours).

Comment: This post should be marked as the answer as it has 24h cycle completeness

Answer (score 28):

A simple little extension function for this:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime now, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
{
    var time = now.TimeOfDay;
    // Scenario 1: If the start time and the end time are in the same day.
    if (start <= end)
        return time >= start && time <= end;
    // Scenario 2: The start time and end time is on different days.
    return time >= start || time <= end;
}
```

Comment: Good addition Andre. Wouldn't have thought to do an OR comparison for the different day case.

Comment: Great little piece of code but one problem with it. What if you specify the same start and end time. One assumption is that, it may mean it should span over a 24 hour period which means your condition which checks `start <= end` should be change to `start < end` and another assumption might be that it is on the same day but if this is the case, it will likely fail if you use Now.TimeOfDay as it includes milliseconds and causes to be out of range.

Comment: @Thierry Nice catch :) You are welcome to try and fix it.

Comment: Another variation to consider is changing the two `time <= end` to `time < end`.

Answer (score 18):

```
if (new TimeSpan(11,59,0) <= currentTime.TimeOfDay && new TimeSpan(13,01,0) >=  currentTime.TimeOfDay)
{
   //match found
}
```

if you really want to parse a string into a TimeSpan, then you can use:

```
    TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("11:59");
    TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse("13:01");
```

Comment: thank you, after hours i tried for `11:57 pm` and this worked:

`TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(23, 57, 00);
               DateTime date_with_time = mydate.Add(time);`

Answer (score 16):

Try using the TimeRange object in C# to complete your goal.

```
TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange();
timeRange = TimeRange.Parse("13:00-14:00");

bool IsNowInTheRange = timeRange.IsIn(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
Console.Write(IsNowInTheRange);
```

[Here is where I got that example of using TimeRange](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/08/24/timerange-object-for-c/)

Comment: TimeRange is not a class from any C# library. It is an external class that can be downloaded at the link above.

Answer (score 9):

The [`TimeOfDay` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) returns a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) value.

Try the following code:

```
TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if (time > new TimeSpan(11, 59, 00)        //Hours, Minutes, Seconds
 && time < new TimeSpan(13, 01, 00)) {
    //match found
}
```

Also, `new DateTime()` is the same as `DateTime.MinValue` and will always be equal to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`. (Value types cannot have non-empty default values)  You want to use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, the problem is you're comparing a DateTime to a TimeOfDay.  What you need to do is add the .TimeOfDay property to the end of your Convert.ToDateTime() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Will this be simpler for handling the day boundary case? :)

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("22:00");  // 10 PM
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse("02:00");    // 2 AM
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

bool bMatched = now.TimeOfDay >= start.TimeOfDay &&
                now.TimeOfDay < end.TimeOfDay;
// Handle the boundary case of switching the day across mid-night
if (end < start)
    bMatched = !bMatched;

if(bMatched)
{
    // match found, current time is between start and end
}
else
{
    // otherwise ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

4 times checking

```cs
public static void GetTime()
        {
            var dt =  DateTime.Now;
            int hours = dt.Hour;
            int min = dt.Minute;

            if (hours >= 1 && hours <= 12)
            {
                //Good Morning
            }
            else if (hours >= 12 && hours <= 16)
            {
                //Good Afternoon
            }
            else if (hours >= 16 && hours <= 21)
            {
                //Good Evening
            }
            else if (hours >= 21 && hours <= 24)
            {
                //Good Night
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We didn't want our service to run during the night.
So we created this condition to check that current time in within the time window of 9am (today) and 1am (the next day):

```
if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now.Date && DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(1.00) || 
DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(9))
{
 // Current Time is within specified time window.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Linq we can simplify this by this

```
 Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(to - from).TotalHours + 1)
            .Select(i => from.AddHours(i)).Where(date => date.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0) && date.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 using System;

 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
        TimeSpan t=new TimeSpan(20,00,00);//Time to check

        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0); //8 o'clock evening

        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(08, 0, 0); //8 o'clock Morning

        if ((start>=end && (t<end ||t>=start))||(start<end && (t>=start && t<end)))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Mached");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Mached");
        }

    }
 }
```