# C# Date and Time Function

Tags: c#

I want my program to check the present system time and use it to display whether the time at that moment is off peak or peak. please help. thanks

Comment: how do you define "peak" and "off peak"?

Comment: so what is your question and what did you try so far?

Comment: if(IsPeak(DateTime.Now)){ // etc. } LOL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/c-sharp-find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range

Comment: Closers: If you don't get it go to next question. Ignorance is bliss. Question was clear.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
        if (
                DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&  // it's not saturday
                DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&    // it's not sunday
                DateTime.Now.Hour>=8 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)   // it is 08:00 to 16:59
            {
                // work time
            }
```

Comment: Well you have peak time span there but why not saturday and sundays ?

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 12, 9, 10, 0, 0)); //10 o'clock
DateTime end = new DateTime(2009, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0)); //12 o'clock
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if ((now > start) && (now < end))
{
   //match found
}
```

Comment: This will only work on december 9, 2009.

Comment: I think the OP wants to check on a certain time on every day. Take a look at my answer.