# Comparing times without date?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble comparing times.

From what I have researched it most likely is due to the time not having a date.

My code,
This gets a `dateTime` value from the database.

```
var getDateTime = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(p => p.Staff_No ==
      SelectedEmployee.Key && p.Date_Data == day).Select(p => p.Time_Data_1).ToList();
DateTime dateTimeGet = Convert.ToDateTime(getDateTime);
```

`dateTimeGet` returns a value like this `"2012/12/12 15:03:00.000"`

I then declare variables to hold the time.

```
TimeSpan startCompare = TimeSpan.Parse("15:00");
TimeSpan endCompare = TimeSpan.Parse("21:00");
```

Then comparing the values [Compare DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range)

```
if ((endCompare > dateTimeGet) && (startCompare < dateTimeGet))
     {
        //match found
     }
```

I am getting a compile error,

```
operands cannot be given to to type timespan and datetime
```

How do I compare times in this situation?

Comment: [TimeSpan.Compare Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Use `DateTime.TimeOfDay` perhaps? Then you'd be comparing two `TimeSpan` values...

Comment: @JonSkeet, that did the trick, thanks for that. Any idea why this post would be down voted? I did my best to find any of the answers before I posted here, as I am self taught thus far. I bought your book a couple months ago, still a bit advanced for me, but already found some great useful things even a person of my level can use. Thanks again.

Comment: @KyloRen its probably just because of the formatting, the way you've laid out your question is a little difficult to read

Comment: @MikeT, sorry about that, did not know how else to put this. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just edit your code like this:

```
if ((endCompare > dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay) && (startCompare < dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay))
     {
        //match found
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create `DateTime` values instead of `TimeSpan` to compare the value, using the `Date` of your db time:

```
DateTime startCompare = dateTimeGet.Date.AddHours(15);
DateTime endCompare = dateTimeGet.Date.AddHours(21);
if ((endCompare > dateTimeGet) && (startCompare < dateTimeGet))
{
    // match found
}
```

---

In the example you showed, actually would be enough to compare the `Hour` part of `dateTimeGet`:

```
if (dateTimeGet.Hour >= 15 && dateTimeGet.Hour <= 21)
    // match found
```

Comment: UV for taking the time to help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are comparing time with date in `endCompare > dateTimeGet` so you are getting the error

> operands cannot be given to to type timespan and datetime

To compare time-span you need to extract the time from date in `dateTimeGet` by simply using `TimeOfDay`.

```
if ((endCompare > dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay) && (startCompare < dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay))
 {
    //match found
 }
```

This will convert the date into time. For more details about `TimeOfDay`[click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)  Hope this works fine for you.

Comment: by mistake I have added to `ToShortTimeString()`. You need to add 'TimeOfDay'. Edited my ans please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, as you rightly say, you are comparing dates to times

A `time-span` is a measurement of time measured in Hours, where as a `date-time` is a measurement of time measured in days

so `2012/12/12 15:03:00.000` is approximately `735248.625 days` or `17645967 hours`
which you are then comparing to a timespan of `15 hours`

so you need to either add `735248 days` to your time span or drop `735248 days` form your Date

both can be easily done
If you call the time `TimeOfDay` property on the date it will ignore the days and just return `0.625 days` as `15 hours`

Which means your code would  look like this

`if ((endCompare > dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay ) && (startCompare < dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay))`

OR

If you add the time span to the at midnight date it will create the correct date time for comparation

Which means your code would  look like this

`if ((dateTimeGet.Date + endCompare > dateTimeGet ) && (dateTimeGet.Date + startCompare < dateTimeGet.TimeOfDay))`

Comment: UV for taking the time to help. Thanks