# How to Query for search time using system time in a MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I have a database table like the figure shown below,

[image]

what i want is write a query to get the current system time is in which time slot. As the result i want to retrieve the line of the relevant time slot. Is there anyone can help me with this?

Comment: mysql date/time "math" is easy. `where timevalue BETWEEN earliertime AND latertime`. but you don't have time values in your db. you have **STRINGS**, and now you're in for a lot of pain converting all those strings to proper date/time values.

Comment: And in bigger picture terms, this is not a jobs board. We are not here to "help" you do your job. You write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: i can change them anytime.. because i'm trying this only for testing purposes

Comment: You can use the logic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range#21343435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create table in following format

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (tid int,tname varchar(10),starttime time,endtime time);

INSERT INTO TEST values (1,"a", "00:00:00","07:00:00");
INSERT INTO TEST values (2,"b", "07:00:00","19:00:00");
INSERT INTO TEST values (3,"c", "19:00:00","23:59:50");

s

elect * from TEST where starttime<time(now()) and endtime>time(now());

    +------+-------+-----------+----------+
    | tid  | tname | starttime | endtime  |
    +------+-------+-----------+----------+
    |    3 | c     | 19:00:00  | 23:59:50 |
    +------+-------+-----------+----------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok thanks its working.. :)