# C# check timespan between two timespans

Tags: c#, timespan

first of all i checked this solution:

[Find if current time falls in a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range)

and tried to compare timespans like that solution

```
public Boolean CalculateDalUren(DateTime datum, TimeSpan? dalStart, TimeSpan? dalEnd)
    {
        Boolean isDal = false;
        TimeSpan timeBetween = datum.TimeOfDay;

        if ((timeBetween >= dalStart))&&(timeBetween < dalEnd)
            {
                isDal = true;
            }
        }
        return isDal;
    }
```

Note that `dalStart` is either 21:00 or 23:00 and `dalEnd` is pretty much always 07:00. And I convert the `DateTime` to a `Timespan`.

Now if a Timespan for example is 23:00 then the time is bigger or the same as `dalStart` but because (and this is an assumption) it is later then `dalEnd` it will still see the if statement as false. vice versa when its 02:00 hours. Then its not later then `dalStart` but earlier then `dalEnd`.

I think this is because my timespan covers 2 days. 21:00 hours from one day, to 07:00 hours the next day. Is there a workaround for this? So i can check if a time is between 21:00 and 07:00 the next morning.

Comment: A timespan is not bound to any point in time, it's simply a description of a *duration of time*. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: TImeSpan != Time, so 21:00 means 21 hours, not 9.p.m.

Comment: yes and at 00:00 time = 0 and thus i cannot compare anymore. Thats the point i guess.
@MathiasR.Jessen I want the `boolean IsDal` to be true when the time in the given `DateTime` is between the times i give in the 2 `TimeSpan` which are most of the time 21:00 and 07:00 hours. So if the time in `DateTime` = 02:00 it should return true, if its 14:00 hours false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this matches your requirement.

If dalEnd is lesser than dalStart, It should be the TimeSpan of the nextday.

```
    public Boolean CalculateDalUren(DateTime datum, TimeSpan? dalStart, TimeSpan? dalEnd)
    {
        Boolean isDal = false;
        DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Today; 
        DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Today;

        //Check whether the dalEnd is lesser than dalStart
        if (dalStart >= dalEnd)
        {
            //Increase the date if dalEnd is timespan of the Nextday 
            EndDate = EndDate.AddDays(1); 
        }

        //Assign the dalStart and dalEnd to the Dates
        StartDate = StartDate.Date + dalStart.Value; 
        EndDate = EndDate.Date + dalEnd.Value;

        if ((datum >= StartDate) && (datum <= EndDate))
        {
            isDal = true;
        }
        return isDal;
    }
```

try it.

Comment: Converting the `TimeSpan` to `Datetime` and increasing the day `if (timeBetween.TimeOfDay < endDate.TimeOfDay)
                {
                    timeBetween = timeBetween.AddDays(1);
                }` 

is the correct answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: I thought dalStart and dalEnd timespan variables are fixed and so i made it that way. It looks nice now. Welcome Proliges.

Answer (score 0):

Create two dates which is the 00:00 of the actual day, add the dalStart, dalEnd timespan to them and 
if ( datum > datetimeFromDalStart and datum < dateTimeFromDalEnd ) ....

Comment: Okay will try this.