# Timer stops entire program

Tags: c#

so I've just made a simple snake game in WinForms and I've only got one problem left. The idea is that I'm gonna implement a power-up that speeds up the player for 10 seconds. I've tried using thread. sleep method to create a timer but that sleeps the entire program. I've also tried playing with the `task.delay` method but without success.

Am I going about this problem the wrong way or am I just missing something? Do you have any tips to get me on the right path? I'm quite new to this so this might be an easy fix.

```
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    using (var task = Task.Delay(10000))
    {
        speedUp = true;
        task.Wait();
    }

    watch.Stop();
    speedUp = false;
```

This is my attempt at the delay. But it seems to pause the entire program for 10 seconds before it continues.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use `sleep` in most real code. Show your attempt using `delay` and explain what went wrong.

Comment: Why don't you actually use a timer? Task.Delay doesn't freeze unless the code explicitly blocks waiting for it with a `.Wait()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check the past time by looking at a clock within your game loop. The property [Environment.TickCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.7.2) provides you with the milliseconds since the last boot or you could do it with [DateTime or Timespan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range). Now instead of sleeping you could check if 10'000 milliseconds have past since the activation of the power-up. This way nothing will get blocked and collecting multiple power-ups within 10 seconds won't screw up the deactivation process.