# Datetime issue to compare to strings in global.aspx in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I'm working on a code which has a logic but I'm unable to compare to them using if can any one please help.

This I have a logic I global.aspx

```
string sTime = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartTime"].ToString();
string eTime = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndTime"].ToString();
DateTime s = DateTime.Parse(sTime);//here i'm getting an Exception while debugging
DateTime e = DateTime.Parse(eTime);
DateTime nTime = DateTime.Now;
if (nTime >= s || nTime < s)
{
    InvokeUnderMaintenance();
}
```

Exception

> System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233033   Message=String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
>          at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
>          at EsiTrak.Web.MvcApplication.Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() in
>   C:\Project\EsitrakWebEnablement\EsiTrak.Web\Global.asax.cs:line 138
>   InnerException:
>
> message::An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

This I have taken in webconfig file as time starttime and end time values

```
<add key="StartTime" value="12"/>
<add key="EndTime" value="18"/>
```

Can any one tell me how to comapre start time and end time  with current time using `||` operator or `&&` operator?

Comment: `12` and `18` are not valid datetime values. It should be like `dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss`

Comment: values of `StartTime` and `EndTime` should be in proper date format. `12` and `18` are hours? if yes then do you want to check date as well?

Comment: They don't includes "enough" information to parse a `DateTime`. I strongly suspect that you need to parse `TimeSpan` instead which can be store time of day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find if current time falls in a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504494/find-if-current-time-falls-in-a-time-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing an integer, which is not of a datetime format. So parse can't identify the format.

If you want to compare with the hours, you can do it as follows:

```
var startHour = Int32.Parse(sTime);
var endHour = Int32.Parse(eTime);
if (nTime.Hour >= startHour && nTime.Hour < eTime)
{
    InvokeUnderMaintenance();
}
```

You can then remove the datetime parse altogether.

Comment: Should be `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Quite right, thanks for the heads up. Copying the original, I kind of missed that.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras if i want to add minutes in key then how can i add can u please tell me and in code too

Comment: `<add key="StartTime" value="12:12"/>`

Comment: `var shour = sTime.Split(":")[0]` and `var smin = sTime.Split(":")[1]`